# How to specify mongodb version from pymongo?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I have a mongodb server version 4.4 and I am upgrading the pymongo version to 4.5.0. Pymongo says it is compatible with vast versions, including 4.4.

How I specify the mongodb version for pymongo?

The problem:

I have used a `$[]` operator, the pymongo 4.5 says I have to use the index for the operation (*** TypeError: list indices must be integer or slice, not str). It is like pymongo is not compatibe with my mongodb version.

Comment: Would you show the specific code that you are having a problem with? ... perhaps some `updateMany` operation using `$[]`? _"pymongo 4.5 says I have to use the index for the operation"_  Is there an error message (if so, please show full error message) and/or doc/manual reference?